# Classification of finite, connected undirected multigraphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to come up with a naming scheme for connected Feynman diagrams, that (as a first step) disregards the actual fields involved. Hence what I have is a set of vertices and a multiset of undirected edges.
Now I want to give "different" (non-isomorphic) Feynman diagrams different names, so that I can have a computer enumerate them in a sensible way.
Hence I would like to have a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and a surjective mapping from $\mathbb{N}^k$ to the set of equivalence classes of all finite,  connected undirected multigraphs (i.e a labelling scheme by a finite set of integers).
I am not sure whether this is possible and if not, please consider restricting the problem to graphs instead of multigraphs - in the case that problem might be solvable.

Some (to a physicist) obvious candidates might be labelling by number of edges, vertices and loops, but that is definitely not sufficient.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you want to hash the graphs? There exist such hashing schemes for graphs. Of course, the hard part is canonically labelling the graph before hashing...

Comment: there is a lot of work on enumeration of Feynman diagrams (e.g., this [old paper](http://www.nbi.dk/~predrag/papers/PRD18-78.pdf)), which is also closely related to enumeration of graphs embedded on surfaces (a.k.a. ["maps"](https://books.google.com/books?id=OVDMBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)). Do you already have some familiarity with this work? Because if not, it might provide for some inspiration.